# position fixed div in absolute positioned div works - but why?

Tags: css, position, css-position, fixed

I need to give an element position fixed, but I can't position it relatively to the viewport, I need it to be positioned relatively to a container.

I managed to do so, but I wonder how and why it works, because actually I think position fixed is ALWAYS positioned relatively to the viewport and NOT to parent elements.

Here my (working) code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

body {
    height: 2000px;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
}

.sidebar {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
}

.fixed {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    position: fixed;
    /* top: 0;
    left: 0; */
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="fixed"></div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tnwLycao/

Element "fixed" can easily be positioned with margins (e.g. margin-left/margin-top). However, when I deactivate the margins and try to position "fixed" with top/left it positions itself relatively to the viewport again, not relatively to the parent container/element.

Can someone give me a hint how and why this works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An element with `position: fixed` is *indeed* positioned relative to the viewport (or browser). However, because it is an absolutely positioned element, it is "positioned relative to the initial [containing block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block) established by the viewport".

This is laid out in the [`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/computed_value) documentation:

> An **absolutely positioned element** is an element whose computed `position` value is `absolute` or `fixed`. The `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left` properties specify offsets from the edges of the element's [containing block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block). (The containing block is the ancestor relative to which the element is positioned.) If the element has margins, they are added to the offset.

That is to say, when you specify `margin-top` and `margin-left`, these values are relative to the **parent**. And because the element is positioned relative to the parent, the default `top` and `left` are **inherited** from the parent. In your example, the `.fixed` element has a `top` value of `100px` because it **inherits** the `top` value of `100px` from `.sidebar` (the parent). When you set `top: 0` on `.fixed`, you are **overriding** this value (going from `top: 108px` to `top: 0`):

[image: Fixed]

Because of this, the element appears to be taken 'out of flow'. However, it is still always positioned relative to the viewport; it just had an initial offset (which it inherited from its parent).